# R random forest what level of error rate is fine

Tags: r, random-forest

I am building the regression model using random forest with package randomForestSRC in R. My error rate at the last line is 16.17. I think it is high, although I am new to the random forest and actually have no idea about the error rate.  My question is what level of error rate is fine? How about my error rate? If it is high, what should I do to deal with it? Here is my result of the model.

> rfsrc(Response~. data=selected_preditors_train, importance=TRUE)

```
                      Sample size: 6508
                 Number of trees: 1000
       Forest terminal node size: 5
   Average no. of terminal nodes: 1388.569
```

No. of variables tried at each split: 11
              Total no. of variables: 25
       Resampling used to grow trees: swr
    Resample size used to grow trees: 6508
                            Analysis: RF-R
                              Family: regr
                      Splitting rule: mse *random*
       Number of random split points: 10
                % variance explained: 43.35
                          Error rate: 16.17

Comment: There's no generic answer to this question. A good error rate is the one that solves your problem to a satisfactory degree.

Answer (score 0):

Your misclassification rate is roughly 16 %, which is not exactly small, at least for a RF. You should look into the optional arguments of RF-SRC to try and fine tune the algorithm.

Most importantly look into `mtry`,`bootstrap`,`samptype`,`sampsize`. <s>Also, do you have a balanced data set? If not, you should either balance it or use the previous arguments to try and fix the majority class bias.</s>

**Edit:** your data may not be appropriate for a random forest model, your % variance explained (RMSE) is also low. You may want to try building a couple of different models (linear, cluster, etc.) to compare the results. If the results are similar among the models, chances are your data is not great. If one of the other models performs better then the others then choose that model.

Comment: What do you mean the balanced data set?

Comment: Ignore that, try tuning the different parameters or try other models.

Comment: Okkk I see. Actually, I am also trying the linear regression.:D